# Syntax error when using "X != 0" in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a problem with my Fortran program that does nothing more than calculating a prime factorization (or should do). That's the error:

```
C:\MinGW\Fortran>gfortran aufg3.f90
aufg3.f90:15.15:

    if (prim(i) != 0 .and. modulo(n, prim(i)) == 0) then
               1
Error: Missing ')' in statement at or before (1)
aufg3.f90:19.7:

    end if
       1
Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
aufg3.f90:34.13:

  if (prim(i) != 0) then
             1
Error: Missing ')' in statement at or before (1)
aufg3.f90:38.5:

  end if
     1
Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
```

I tried everything, but totally have no idea what could be wrong. Thanks for your help. Here is the code:

```
program aufg3
    implicit none
    integer :: n, i
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: prim
    do
        print *, 'Bitte natürliche Zahl eingeben, "0" für Abbruch: '
        read *, n
        if (n == 0) exit
        allocate(prim(2:n))
        call era(prim, n)
        print *, n, ' = 1'
        do
            if (n == 1) exit
            do i = 2, n
                if (prim(i) != 0 .and. modulo(n, prim(i)) == 0) then
                    print *, ' * ', prim(i)
                    n = n / prim(i)
                    exit
                end if
            end do
        end do
        deallocate(prim)
    end do
end program
```

subroutine era(prim, m)
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    integer, dimension(2:m) :: prim
    integer :: i, j
    do i = 2, m
        prim(i) = i
    end do
    do i = 2, integer(sqrt(real(m)))
        if (prim(i) != 0) then
            do j = i*i, m, i
                prim(j) = 0
            end do
        end if
    end do
end subroutine

Comment: I got ninja'd by two other (good) answers, but don't forget to change the `integer(sqrt(real(m)))`, perhaps to `NINT(sqrt(real(m)))`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is Fortran and `!` denotes a comment. So the compiler actually sees

```
if (prim(i)
```

which is no valid statement. The error message you see reflects that.

"Not equal" in Fortran is `/=` or `.ne.`:

```
 if (prim(i) /= 0 .and. modulo(n, prim(i)) == 0) then
```

and, later on:

```
if (prim(i) /= 0) then
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using the wrong notation for 'not equal to'. Fortran syntax is `/=` or `.NE.`.

So you should be using:

```
if (prim(i) /= 0 .and. modulo(n, prim(i)) == 0) then
```

and

```
if (prim(i) /= 0) then
```

Furthermore, your syntax of `integer(sqrt(real(m)))` is incorrect, perhaps you mean `NINT(sqrt(real(m)))`?

Answer (score 3):

The token for "not equals" in fortran is /= . ! starts a comment, hence the compiler reading line 15 as

```
        if (prim(i)
```

and so is confused because there is no bracket to close the logical expression in the if statement. So simply replace != with /= and it should get rid of this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to Fortran and before worked with C very much, so '!=' just seemed right ;-)